# JavaScript, async await is returning a promise instead of the result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below function. Why am I getting `Promise { <state>: "pending" }` when calling `GetProfile("username")`? What should I do?

```js
const GetProfile = async (username) => {
  await fetch(`${host}/api/v1/getprofile/${username}`).then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.json());
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resp.json()` returns a `Promise` and that's what you are console logging. It should resolve before getting the actual data. Since you are in an `async` function, you could do as below. Notice there is no need to have this `then` block you have.

```js
const GetProfile = async (username) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${host}/api/v1/getprofile/${username}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal `async` function behavior in javascript, they return promises.

In React, you can keep the value in a state.

```
const [profile,setProfile]=useState(null)

    useEffect(()=> {


        const GetProfile = async (username) => {
           const profile = await fetch(`${host}/api/v1/getprofile/${username}`).then(resp => resp.json());
           setProfile(profile)}

        GetProfile(username);

    },[username])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `.then` after your async call, and `resp.json()` also returns a `Promise` which isn't being returned by your `.then()` call.

What happens in your case is:

```
const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/v1/getprofile/${username}`)
return response.json();
```

And because the `json()` function is a Promise itself (which isn't `await`'ed), the read of the `json()` call is the 'Pending' Promise that you're getting.

So to solve this, try either:

```js
await fetch(`${host}/api/v1/getprofile/${username}`).then((resp) => resp.json())
```

or

```js
const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/v1/getprofile/${username}`)

return await response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `async` [function always returns promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value). What you need to do is to execute it with `await` and you can extract the result, or chain it with `then` and move on.

I made an example with `await`:

```js
const GetProfile = async (username) => {
  await fetch(`${host}/api/v1/getprofile/${username}`).then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.json());

    return resp.json()
  });
};


const result = await GetProfile()
console.log(result);
```

NOTE:
You need to return `resp.json()` back from one of `then`s to see the result.